# Rename folder to a random number

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch script, 
I am writing a batch script for renaming a folder to a number and that number should not be the same.. Every time I click the batch file, it should be a random number.

eg:
`folder name is "temp"`

If I run the bat file that folder name should be change to a random number.

eg:

```
1st time : folder name after rename can be "34324"<br/>
2nd time : folder name after rename can be "29389"<br/>
.
.
.
.
.
nth time : folder name after rename can be "xxxxx"
```

please teach me how to do this..

I am a newbie in this field..

Comment: and what part of that you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

I have made this for you:

```
@echo off
:retry
SET /A test=%RANDOM% * 10000 / 100000 + 1
echo %test%
IF EXIST %~dp0\%test% GOTO retry
md "%~dp0\%test%"
GOTO retry
```

It's quite quick 100+ folders per second, so watch out.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks. I Had somewhere to be when I saw the question so I didn't have much time.

Answer (score 1):

This batch file saves the information about the last folder name inside itself. Each time it is run, it retrieves this information. If not found, temp is assumed. If folder does not exist, it is created. If it exists, a new name is searched, the folder is renamed and the information saved inside batch file.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Determine where to work
    if "%cd:~-1%"=="\" ( set "where=%cd%" ) else ( set "where=%cd%\" )

    rem Determine what to search for in the current file
    set "testString=:::set lastName=[0-9][0-9]*"

    rem Retrieve the last name used
    set "lastName="
    for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /r /b /e /c:"%testString%" "%~f0"') do %%a
    if not defined lastName set "lastName=temp"

    rem If the last folder does not exist, create it and finish
    if not exist "%where%%lastName%\" (
        mkdir "%where%\%lastName%" 
        echo(Folder [%lastName%] has been created
        goto endProcess 
    )

    rem Search for a new name
;:newNameLoop
    set "newName=%random%"
    if "%newName%"=="%lastName%" goto newNameLoop
    if exist "%where%%newName%" goto newNameLoop

    rem Rename the folder to the new name
    ren "%where%%lastName%" "%newName%" 2>nul && set "save=1" || set "save="

    rem If there were no problems, save the new name in current batch file
    if defined save (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /r /b /e /v /c:"%testString%" "%~f0" ^& break ^> "%~f0"') do >>"%~f0" echo(%%b
        >>"%~f0" echo(:::set lastName=%newName%
        echo Renamed [%lastName%] into [%newName%]
    ) else (
        echo Rename operation failed. Ensure folder is not in use
    )

    rem End of the process, clean and exit
;:endProcess
    endlocal
    exit /b
```

And no, the added semicolon in labels is not a typo error. They (or other character) are needed to avoid problems with the `delims=:`